# Не работает message.content discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Столкнулся с проблемой, что message.content возвращает пустую строку, то есть он просто не читает содержимое моих сообщений. В статье указано, что пострадают только боты на 100+ серверах, а мой создан 2 дня назад и сидит только на моем сервере. Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает message.content и как это исправить.
https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен утвердить своего бота. Читай внимательнее "К ЧЕМ ПОТЕРЯЕТ ДОСТУП НЕУТВЕРЖДЕННЫЙ БОТ?". Там написано:

"Если ваш бот или приложение не одобрено для содержимого сообщения, следующие поля объекта сообщения в полезных нагрузках шлюза и API будут пустыми — либо пустой строкой, либо пустым массивом, в зависимости от типа данных, — когда вы  получаете  сообщение:

```
content
embeds
attachments
components
```

"

Увы, но не получится тебе помочь! Тебе нужно сделать так, чтобы твой бот был на 100 серверов.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш бод удовлетворяет условиям и не присутствует на 100+ серверах, то вам достаточно зайти в панель разработчика, раздел апликации, выбрать нужного бота, перейти в раздел "Bot" (меню слева), найти пункт "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" и тыкнуть на переключатель(чтоб стал синеньким), далее нажать на зеленую кнопочку save во всплывшем окошке снизу.
Возможно потребуется перезапуск бота(но это не точно).
На всякий делается это тут: https://discord.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
# После этого флага True, появлятся невидимые сообщения
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)
```